# Laravel: How to solve "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-migrations

I am making migrations where there is a particular migration that maps one table with various other tables using a foreign key. and I am getting the following error while running the migration.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `bookmaps` add constraint `bookmaps_subject_id_foreign` foreign key (`subject_id`) references `subject` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Here is the migration that is creating the error:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('bookmaps', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('book_id')->unique();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('subject_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('grade_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('author_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('catagory_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('language_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('bookmaps', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('book')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('subject_id')->references('id')->on('subject')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('grade_id')->references('id')->on('grade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('author')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('catagory_id')->references('id')->on('catagories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('language_id')->references('id')->on('language')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Migrations for other related tables are:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('book', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('discription')->nullable();
            $table->string('book_file')->nullable();
            $table->string('card_image')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('book', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
     
    }
```

The table created by above migration is only mapped by foreign key rest of the below migrations are not mapped.

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subject', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('subject_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('grade', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('grade_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('author', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('author_name');
            $table->string('author_discription')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('grade', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('grade_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('author', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('author_name');
            $table->string('author_discription')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('catagories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('catagories_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('language', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('language_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Add primary key

Comment: Is there a way I can make book_id as both foreign and primary key? As it is a table that is used to map and used like one to one relation.

Comment: When add a custom primary key, you need to define that on your model `protected $primaryKey = "book_id";`

Comment: @STA I did not create model file right away and was thinking of creating it later. It shouldn't affect while performing migrations I think.

Comment: Yes, but your migration,  you need primary key in your migration for making relationship

Comment: I added a PK column `$tablel->id()` in the maps table as you suggest but the problem stills persists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217219/discussion-between-riwaj-chalise-and-sta).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the subject migration before the bookmarks. When Laravel tries to migrate the bookmarks table, there is a foreign key linked to the subject table that it does not find.

Comment: This is not an answer, please ask your queation on the comment. Not as answer

Comment: This type of response is better suited for comments. And yes all other migrations are created before bookmaps migrations.